# Ajax method to post score achieved within Phaser game

Tags: ajax, phaser-framework

I have a Phaser game that runs just fine. I need to submit score to my server which has a action that can accept the score. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try this :

```
var my_score = 20; 

function submit_score(my_score) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("my_score", my_score);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'post.php', true);
    xhr.send(fd);

}
```

here is the PHP file

```
<?php 

    $score = $_POST["my_score"];

    echo $score;

?>
```